# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This feature requires ASM8_EXPERIMENTAL

Tags: java, maven-3, java-bytecode-asm, spring-boot-2, java-14

I try to run the [application](https://github.com/sleshJdev/incubator/tree/master/spring-jdbc-record-row-mapper) using spring boot + jdk14(records) + junit5 + maven, but unfortunately, I cannot address an issue with asm. In the internet I only could find [this](https://gitlab.ow2.org/asm/asm/commit/f14f4bac065781b3ac0bf20b00073e8151cf0b9a) asm GitLab commit. Afaik this is an experimental feature and there is no official build. So, then what is the way to run project on jdk14?

Find below a stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/Workspace/incubator/spring-jdbc-record-row-mapper/target/test-classes/by/slesh/spring/jdbc/core/Billionaire.class]; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This feature requires ASM8_EXPERIMENTAL

at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:454)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:316)
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.AnnotatedClassFinder.scanPackage(AnnotatedClassFinder.java:90)
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.AnnotatedClassFinder.findFromPackage(AnnotatedClassFinder.java:82)
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.AnnotatedClassFinder.findFromClass(AnnotatedClassFinder.java:68)
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.getOrFindConfigurationClasses(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:232)
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.processMergedContextConfiguration(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:149)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:395)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:294)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:108)
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:99)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:137)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:122)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.lambda$getOrComputeIfAbsent$0(ExtensionValuesStore.java:81)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.get(ExtensionValuesStore.java:182)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(ExtensionValuesStore.java:84)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(ExtensionValuesStore.java:88)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.NamespaceAwareStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(NamespaceAwareStore.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.getTestContextManager(SpringExtension.java:213)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.beforeAll(SpringExtension.java:77)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllCallbacks$7(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:359)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:359)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:189)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:78)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:132)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1510)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
at 

org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
    Suppressed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/Workspace/incubator/spring-jdbc-record-row-mapper/target/test-classes/by/slesh/spring/jdbc/core/Billionaire.class]; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This feature requires ASM8_EXPERIMENTAL
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:454)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:316)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.AnnotatedClassFinder.scanPackage(AnnotatedClassFinder.java:90)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.AnnotatedClassFinder.findFromPackage(AnnotatedClassFinder.java:82)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.AnnotatedClassFinder.findFromClass(AnnotatedClassFinder.java:68)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.getOrFindConfigurationClasses(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:232)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.processMergedContextConfiguration(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:149)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:395)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:294)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:99)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:137)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:122)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.lambda$getOrComputeIfAbsent$0(ExtensionValuesStore.java:81)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.get(ExtensionValuesStore.java:182)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.remove(ExtensionValuesStore.java:98)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.NamespaceAwareStore.remove(NamespaceAwareStore.java:73)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.afterAll(SpringExtension.java:89)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllCallbacks$13(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:425)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllCallbacks$14(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:425)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1510)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeAfterAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:425)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.after(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:213)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.after(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:78)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:145)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:145)
        ... 27 more
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This feature requires ASM8_EXPERIMENTAL
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor.visitRecordComponentExperimental(ClassVisitor.java:305)
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readRecordComponent(ClassReader.java:931)
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:705)
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:401)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:50)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:132)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:430)
        ... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This feature requires ASM8_EXPERIMENTAL
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor.visitRecordComponentExperimental(ClassVisitor.java:305)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readRecordComponent(ClassReader.java:931)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:705)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:401)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:50)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:132)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:430)
    ... 54 more

Process finished with exit code 255
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like ASM changes were merged to Spring Core 5.2.4. You can rollback to Spring Boot 2.3.0.M2 which uses Spring Core 5.2.3

Comment: According to [5.2.4 release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/releases) they upgraded ASM to version 7.3 (which contains changes that cause this `This feature requires ASM8_EXPERIMENTAL` error). Using `2.3.0.M2` instead of `2.3.0M3` helped me but I'm not sure if it is Spring issue or not

Comment: Thanks, I've explicitly specified spring-core 5.2.3.RELEASE and it worked

Answer (score 1):

This is now fixed in Spring Framework 5.2.5, and Spring Boot 2.3 M4 (the next release due in about a week) is already using this version so it should be solved.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24722

Answer (score -1):

in my case it has been fixed when i changed this settings

goto Run -> Edit Confuguration -> select app -> Profiling

uncheck "Enable additional support for older devices"

[image]

Comment: This is for a spring boot application?